# Python to Excel Gets Data in bulks

Tags: python, vba, excel

I have a code that gets data from a site and should pastes to excel sheet. Till this point everything is fine except excel part. The data comes to excel in bulks I do not understand why. Normally it should be like ;

```
Name1
Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 
Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4

Name2
Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 
Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4

Name3
Date1 Date2 Date3 Date4 ....
Data1 Data2 Data3 Data4 ...
```

But I get same data - name1 for a range of A1:EO434 and then again it updates all cells for Name2 and Name3 and so on. So when the loop finishes I see only the last data copied to excel range of A1:EO434

here it is;

```
.... ... ... .... .. ... .. ...
     data_district = json.loads(r_district.text)
     data_district = map(dict.values, data_district[u'output'][u'resultset'][u'record'][u'data'])
     i = 0
     for row in data_district:

         Range("A"+ str(i + 1) ).value = zip(*data_district) #Not OK.
         i = i+3
```

PS: Here is the full code;

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart
import requests
import json

payload_city = {'cityId':3969, 'cmd':'districts'}
url = "https://www.garantimortgage.com/apps/Socket/Webservice.ashx"
r_city = requests.post(url, data=payload_city)


data_city = json.loads(r_city.text) #json to python data structure conversion
wb = Workbook()
mydict = data_city[:] #translation in to dictionary
for i in list(range(len(mydict))):
 print  data_city[i]["DistrictName"]
 payload_district = {'cityId':data_city[i]["CityId"], 'lbDistricts':data_city[i]["DistrictCode"], 'criter':149,'startdate':'2003-01','cmd':'result','areaCode':data_city[i]["AreaWideCode"]}

 r_district = requests.post(url, data=payload_district)

 data_district = json.loads(r_district.text)
 data_district = map(dict.values, data_district[u'output'][u'resultset'][u'record'][u'data'])
 i = 0
 for row in data_district:

     Range("A"+ str(i + 1) ).value = zip(*data_district)
     i = i+3
```

Comment: May be worth looking at the csv module as an alternative

Comment: Have a look at a basic Python tutorial. E.g. `mydict` is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary. Looping through lists is simply `for i in mylist:` nothing of the things needed you do with `list`, `range`, `len`. For `xlwings`, look at: http://docs.xlwings.org/datastructures.html - no loops required.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.@thefragileomen, @FelixZumstein. However, the reason why i use loops is that the stucture of the data. So, i have cities, under cities i have districs and every distric has its own data. That is why i thought i have to run the loop

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer in case someone needs, I post it here;
When I take out the second loop it worked properly such;

```
j = 0
.......
.......
......
for loop 
....
...

 Range("A" + str(j + 1)).value = zip(*data_district)
 j=j+4
```

Comment: Looping through cells with xlwings is very slow. First put together a list of list with your loop, then send that over to Excel. Also look at index notation Range((i,j)).